# Firebase 3 way data binding not working as expected

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have an AngularJS service that returns a firebase ref.

```
.factory('sessionManager', ['$firebase','$scope', function($firebase){
    var ref=new Firebase('https://telechat.firebaseio.com/sessions');
    return $firebase(ref);
  }])
```

In the controller, I have added the dependency and called `$bind`.

```
$scope.items=sessionManager;
$scope.items.$bind($scope,'sessions').then(function(unbind){
      unbind();
    });
```

But when I print it to the console, the returned data has a collection of functions like `$add` , `$set` ,.. etc in addition to the array of data.

Why is this occurring? Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: You seem to be printing the Firebase dataref or snapshot, instead of just its data. Did you try printing the `.val()` of your snapshot? See https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html

Comment: Yea , that was what I thought in the beginning. but I am doing it like in this https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/index.html . $scope.sessions is supposed to have the data .  The object has no following methods  .val() or .on() ---> returns error .

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. `$scope.items` isn't just a plain Javascript object, it's a Firebase ref. It defeats the purpose of 3 way databinding.

Comment: Should be a bug I hope.

Comment: The funny thing is you can still modify the object directly and it'll reflect the changes. For example, you can do `$scope.sessions[10] = {username: "admin"}` and it adds a new session with key 10.

Comment: But when I want to get the data in an array format... cant do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you may be under the impression that $bind() is a transformation of the $firebase object into a raw data array or object. In essence, the only difference between a $firebase instance and $bind is that data is local changes are automagically pushed back to Firebase from Angular. Whereas, when you use $firebase without $bind, you need to call $save to push local changes.

Keeping in mind that $firebase is a wrapper on the Firebase API and not a simple data array, you can still treat it like raw data in most cases.

To iterate data in a Firebase object, you can use ngRepeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, item) in $sessions">{{item|json}}</li>
```

Or if you want to apply filters that depend on arrays:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, item) in $sessions | orderByPriority | filter:searchText">
```

Or in a controller using $getIndex:

```
angular.forEach($scope.sessions.$getIndex(), function(key) {
    console.log(key, $scope.sessions[key]);
});
```

The $add/$update/etc methods mentoined are part of the [$firebase object's API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html). The [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/index.html) and the [tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#tutorial/angular/0.html) should be great primers for understanding this process.

This is also a part of the API that is continuing to evolve to better match the Angular way of doing things and feedback from users.

Comment: What if I want to push an element to the array? I can't do `$scope.sessions.push({username: 'newname'})`

Comment: Dont think that will work . Will have to use $scope.sessions.$add({new value}).

Comment: The earlier angularfire allowed copying the $scope value to another variable and this new variable was 3 way binded . But $firebase's 3 way data binding doesnt allow that I think .