# How to print object returned by Firebase service as array (to the console)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angular + Firebase stack.

I would like to convert object returned by Firebase:

[image: Firebase object]

into the array so it can be printed in the console like this:

```
 [ {object}, {object}, {object}, {object}, {Object} ];
```

I know how to use "orderByPriority" filter in template but I don't know how to use it inside controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase 3 way data binding not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267077/firebase-3-way-data-binding-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: I think this question doesn't have much in common with [Firebase 3 way data binding not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22267077/617996) except that they are both related to Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print an array of returned objects to the console, you need to apply `orderByPriority` filter (as you already found out) and use `$watchCollection` to watch for changes (as data are returned `asynchronously`):

```
    $scope.$watchCollection('messages', function() {
      console.log(orderByPriorityFilter($scope.messages));   
    });
```

You can check out the working solution in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BkB0r9cHNndj1rDLxbjT?p=preview).

Comment: ok, but check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/xa94ZXDore27rU2YBAUZ?p=preview) I have made some changes in your above code...just check line no. 23 & 24.